# How can I terminate API call in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I am new to iPhone. I have faced a new problem. I have an API interaction in my app. That API take long time for loading. When I terminate my app manually, while loading that API my app closed. Then I would open my app it will closed immediately.

Can any one help me how can I terminate or kill the API call while cancel it?

Comment: You might want to move your text out of the Code snippet, so we can read your post.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean a web API call, like google's geoservices. To do this, you will need to make the call using a NSURLConnection. This way, you can cancel a call anytime using [connection cancel].

Try this tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/ It's meant for a JSON api call. If you need another API, just start reading from 'fetching JSON over HTTP', there they set up a NSURLConnection. If you retain this connection until it's done, you will be able to make the [connection cancel] call at anytime.

Using the UIApplicationDelegate, you can detect the app entering the background.