# How to terminate API call in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how can i terminate api call in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352937/how-can-i-terminate-api-call-in-iphone)

I have an API call in my iPhone app. That API call take more time for loading (near 100 sec). while the API processing, I hit the home button of my app, the app terminated, but the API call doesn't terminated.

How can I terminate API call?

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352937/how-can-i-terminate-api-call-in-iphone). If you have new information, please edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Like e.James said, look at the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

However, you might be more interested in either [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) or 
[applicationWillTerminate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) (depending on whether or not the device supports multitasking), because [applicationWillResignActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) will also be called in cases like when the user receives a phone call, or other similar interruptions (see documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. You can cancel the API call in the [applicationWillResignActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) method, which is called just before the app goes into background mode.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you duped the question, i'll post my answer here too:

I suppose you mean a web API call, like google's geoservices. To do this, you will need to make the call using a NSURLConnection. This way, you can cancel a call anytime using [connection cancel].

Try [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) tutorial. It's meant for a JSON api call. If you need another API, just start reading from 'fetching JSON over HTTP', there they set up a NSURLConnection. If you retain this connection until it's done, you will be able to make the [connection cancel] call at anytime.

Using the UIApplicationDelegate, you can detect the app entering the background.